# Android facebook login with SSO get result_cancelled

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

i have an application using facebook login to authorize user. When I click button login with facebook the application show dialog facebook permission, but after I click OK, the onActivityResult is give `resultCode = RESULT_CANCELLED` instead of `RESULT_OK`

this is my code to login with facebook

```
    OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(a);
    op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
    op.setCallback(null);
    op.setPermissions(permissions);
    op.setRequestCode(Constants.FB_LOGIN);
    Session session = new Builder(a).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForRead(op);
```

and this is my code in my activity in onActivityResult

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == Constants.FB_LOGIN){
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);       
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();  
            fbac.setDataFB(session.getAccessToken(), false, true);
        }
    }
```

if i use `op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);` the onActivityResult give resultCode = RESULT_OK, but i want use `op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);`
please help me

EDITED
i set the call back to only show the session state
    op.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

```
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Log.d("session state", state.name());
            }
        });
```

and I also not checking what the resultCode in onActivityResult, in there i put the code for requesting user data using `Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {` with the session from `Session.getActiveSession()` but the result is user (GraphUser) is null
and this is the logcat

```
01-10 10:21:18.957: D/session state(14109): OPENING 
01-10 10:21:25.657: D/session state(14109): CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED
01-10 10:21:25.657: D/user(14109): user null
```

Comment: Is there anything in logcat, or in the "exception" parameter of your StatusCallback? The most likely cause of SSO not working is if you don't have the key hash set up properly.

Comment: there is not anything in logcat, only resultCode is 0, means RESULT_CANCELLED, and I set the Callback null

Comment: Is your key hash set up properly? Please implement a callback, that's how errors are passed back. Also, don't check for resultCode == RESULT_OK, just pass the whole result to Session.getActiveSession.

Comment: yes the key hash set up properly, please check my edited question, the logcat from sessionState in callBack is OPENING and then after user klik OK the state is CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

Comment: yeah you right, my key hash is different with the facebook app settings, but how it became different? i used to use the old keyhash for using facebook sdk?

Comment: Were you building a release apk? That usually uses a different keystore.